# AngularJS route with trailing slash failing

Tags: angularjs

I have a route that looks like and this and ***works***:

```
when('/videos', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/partial1',
  controller: 'MyCtrl1'
}).
```

However, if I add a named group to the when:

```
when('/videos/:video_id', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/partial1',
  controller: 'MyCtrl1'
}).
```

it does ***not work*** when I try to visit `videos/1` in the browser.

I get a bunch of errors in the console, along the lines of:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What's strange is that I also get an error that says

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:
```

and the console says that is coming from a file named:

```
video_id:13
```

It seems like `video_id` is being interpreted as a file of its own?

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that you could only do this with route names, and not with template names. Whenever you use `:` to designate a route parameter, it gets stored in `$routeParams`; however, I don't think there is an analogous service for use with template names. If so, the errors make sense.

Keep in mind that the route paths are the outward-facing paths seen in the URL. You will not see the template names in this way; the point of this code is to connect them. There is probably a way to restructure your application so that you can do what you want but also only have one partial per route, as I think is the best practice.

Comment: Ah my bad I mistyped that..the trailing slash should belong to the `when` part.

Comment: OK, so you are not trying to use : in the template URL?

Comment: I don't think you can have trailing slashes in your route URL. I'm looking at one of my projects and none of my routes end in `/`.

Comment: Yes, I think the problem is the trailing slash. I don't understand the problem though - you say you want to use a route parameter but why aren't you?

Comment: Do you have an `otherwise` specified? Normally when you try to load a route that doesn't exist, you'll be redirected to `/` or whatever you specified to be the default path. That said, the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` is suspicious. You may want to post more complete code so we can take a look.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49696/discussion-between-moby-and-sighrobot)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting that error because your server is responding with a 404 or some other unexpected response.  According to the [$routeProvider documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) you can't even use `:` to specify a route parameter for the templateUrl but you can use a function

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {Array.<Object>} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route

so then you can do

```
var partial1UrlBuilder = function(routeParams) {
  return 'partials/partial1/' + routeParams.id;
};

...

when('/view1', {
  templateUrl: partial1UrlBuilder,
  controller: 'MyCtrl1'
}).
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistyped initially. The trailing slash should belong to `when` and not the templateUrl. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
when('/videos/:video_id', {
  templateUrl: '/partials/partial1',
  controller: 'MyCtrl1'
})
```

I too faced same problem , prefixing slash before partials solved the issue.